# How to compute GPS time of week (gps_tow) from std::chrono::gps_clock::now?

Tags: c++, gps, c++20, c++-chrono

How to compute GPS time of week (gps_tow) from `std::chrono::gps_clock::now`?

`gps_clock::now` is provided by latest compiler/std: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/gps_clock/now.

How to compute GPS time of week starting from there https://godbolt.org/z/81vK3n3rG using `std::chrono` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the gps epoch starts at the beginning of the week (where they defined the beginning of the week as Sunday 00:00:00 UTC).

```
auto gps_now = gps_clock::now();
cout << "GPS Time: " << gps_now << std::endl;
auto gps_weeks = floor<weeks>(gps_now);
auto gps_tow = gps_now - gps_weeks;
cout << "GPS week: " << gps_weeks.time_since_epoch()/weeks{1} << '\n';
cout << "GPS tow: " << gps_tow << '\n';
```

You just `floor` the time to `weeks` precision, and then subtract off the integral number of `weeks` from the time to get time of week.

This gives you a `duration` of the same precision that `gps_now` has (`nanoseconds` with gcc).  This formats the `tow` as just a number of `nanoseconds`.  You can reformat it into days, hours, minutes and fractional seconds with:

```
auto gps_days = floor<days>(gps_tow);
gps_tow -= gps_days;
cout << "GPS tow: " << gps_days.count() << " days " << format("{:%T}", gps_tow) << '\n';
```

The [full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h6zsh3cfY) currently outputs:

```
GPS Time: 2023-08-26 12:49:22.394953138
GPS week: 2276
GPS tow: 564562394953138ns
GPS tow: 6 days 12:49:22.394953138
```

Note that the although the gps epoch was defined to start at the beginning of the UTC week:

```
cout << format("{:%a %F %T %Z}", clock_cast<utc_clock>(gps_seconds{})) << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
Sun 1980-01-06 00:00:00 UTC
```

The GPS weeks and UTC weeks become unaligned by 1 second every time there is a leap second (because *all* GPS weeks are exactly 7*86400 seconds long).  So currently the GPS week begins 18s before the UTC week:

```
cout << format("{:%a %F %T %Z}", gps_seconds{weeks{2276}}) << '\n';
cout << format("{:%a %F %T %Z}", clock_cast<utc_clock>(gps_seconds{weeks{2276}})) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
Sun 2023-08-20 00:00:00 GPS
Sat 2023-08-19 23:59:42 UTC
```

Note how you can use `clock_cast` to convert back and forth between UTC and GPS time points.  This provides a more homogenous interface compared to the `from_utc`/`to_utc` static member functions.  But otherwise they are the same thing.  `clock_cast` calls `from_utc`/`to_utc` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc-13 and C++20:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

int main() {
    auto utc_now = std::chrono::utc_clock::now();
    std::cout << "UTC Time: " << utc_now << std::endl;

    auto tai_now = std::chrono::tai_clock::from_utc(utc_now);
    std::cout << "TAI Time: " << tai_now << std::endl;

    auto gps_now = std::chrono::gps_clock::from_utc(utc_now);
    std::cout << "GPS Time: " << gps_now << std::endl;

    auto gps_weeks = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::weeks>(gps_now);
    auto gps_tow = gps_now - gps_weeks;
    std::cout << "GPS TOW: " << gps_tow << std::endl;
    
    auto gps_days = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(gps_tow);
    std::cout << "GPS TOW: " << gps_days.count() << " days, ";
    std::cout << std::format("{:%T}", gps_tow - gps_days) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```